# What is usage() in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm new to shell scripting, learning it independently, and I'm seeing a lot of scripts with a `usage()` function. For example:

```
 usage()  
 {  
 echo "Usage: $0 filename"  
 exit 1  
 }
```

Which kind of functions should be called `usage`? And is there relation to "usage statement"? I couldn't find any basic definition for this...

Comment: For more detailed descriptions in a `usage()` you can use a `heredoc` see: [**Here Documents - The Linux Documentation Project**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). Which is often what you find when the `usage()` gives detailed information on the script, along with a list of options and a description of each. It prevents using numerous `echo` or `printf` statements one after the other...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's a just a convention.  When something is wrong with the values supplied on the command line, people often use a function called usage() to tell you the problem/the values expected.   For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
    usage
else
    filename=$1
fi
...
```

Comment: Also convention: print usage to stdout (&1) when help (`-h,--help`) is requested; print usage to stderr (&2) otherwise.

Comment: The "();" in the given example does not appear to be in POSIX.

Comment: Right you are, a little c crept in there.  Removed.

Answer (score 6):

When you check the arguments sent to the program, you'll sometimes have to notify the user that they failed the command.

For example, if you expect your program to be called with `myprogram filename`, then you will call `usage` if there is no parameter or more than 1 parameter.

Instead of having the same message at several locations in your code with the content of `usage`, it's a better practice to do only one function.